# What is the purpose of the [replacements] tag

Tags: discussion

The [replacements](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/replacements) tag (and the [replace](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/replace) tag) don't have a tag wiki, and I'm wondering how they're meant to be used.  Are they supposed to be used on questions on how to replace things?  Are those even needed?

Comment: Good question ;-)

Answer (score 3):

At the time of writing this there are [29 questions tagged](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/replacements) <kbd>replacements</kbd> and [82 questions](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/replace+-replacements) tagged <kbd>replace</kbd>.

I find these tags are being used in the following ways:

- Indication that a replacement occurred (circumstantial clarification)
- Request for instruction on how to replace (used in the verb sense here)
- Assessment of the suitability/compatibility of replacement parts

I don't think the first two use cases warrant a separate tag; the latter can be covered by a more specific categorization such as [compatibility](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compatibility) (which isn't used enough by the look of things).